# Howto read out SharedMemory Mapped File as different datatypes on c++ side

Tags: c#, c++11, shared-memory

@First of all I´m sorry if the code formatting is not working, it´s my first attempt...

I´m setting up a interprocess communication between a C# WPF application and a C++ DLL (which is used by a 3rd party application). The communication shall be used to communicate several different basic datatypes (bool, (u)integer, float, double, string).
Therefor I planned to use the MemoryMappedFile as Field of unspecified Data with a size that fits my amount of data.
I read in the configuration on both side using the same ConfigFile and then store my byte offsets from on to the other variable.
e.g

```
//bool1 => memory[0]
//int1 => memory[1]
//float1 => memory[5]
//double1 => memory[9]
//int2 => memory[17] and so on...
```

But I´m not able to re-interpret the values on the c++ side without getting exceptions.

The SharedMemory communication itself works properly. I sent data from each side to the other. And If I fill the byte[] on the c# sid with 1 in each field, I can print out the whole buffer on the c++ side as characters and I see a SOH (ascii 0x01) for each field.

```
// read the MapViewOfFile ... works
auto buffer = (char*) MapViewOfFile(this->shm_handle, 
FILE_MAP_READ, 0, 0, this->shm_field_size);


//interpret as std::string and print out 
//makes a bunch of SOH SOH... in my logfile
std::string incomingPayload(buffer);
_HEILOG(incomingPayload);


//this line throws an exception (I´m not able to catch it)
int tmp_int = *reinterpret_cast<int*>(buffer, 0);
_HEILOG("field as int" << tmp_int);

// this block throws also an unknown exception...
void* v = (void*)buffer[0];int* ip = (int*)v;
int testi = *ip; 
_HEILOG("field as int2" << testi );
```

I expected both tries to work, as I expected to be able to navigate through the memory field by `buffer[offset]` (e.g `buffer[0]`, `buffer[1]`, `buffer[5]`... for above example).

And then do a reinterpretation of the upcoming bytes to read the data as bool, int, float or whatever.
But my 3rd Party application throws unknown exceptions and my Logfile has no entries.

I´m thankfull for each hint.

Best Regards
SU52

**Edit:**
After Selvins help I got my major mistake by deferencing the value of the char[] instead of the adress of the char[].

Now I still have problems in reading out an double value:

```
/*
Double 355664.12 as binary in C#
Byte No[13] => 174 as Binary: 10101110
Byte No[14] => 71  as Binary: 01000111
Byte No[15] => 225 as Binary: 11100001
Byte No[16] => 122 as Binary: 01111010
Byte No[17] => 64  as Binary: 01000000
Byte No[18] => 181 as Binary: 10110101
Byte No[19] => 21  as Binary: 00010101
Byte No[20] => 65  as Binary: 01000001
*/
char doublefield[] = {  BYTE(1010,1110),
                            BYTE(0100,0111),
                            BYTE(1110,0001),
                            BYTE(0111,1010),
                            BYTE(0100,0000),
                            BYTE(1011,0101),
                            BYTE(0001,0101),
                            BYTE(0100,0001)
    };

double *double_p = reinterpret_cast<double*>(&doublefield[0]);
std::cout << double_p[0] << std::endl; //355664 missing decimals
```

leads to missing decimals.

I tried to switch the 4 HiBytes with the 4 LoBytes without success.

Does anyone have an Idea where the decimals get lost?
BR

Comment: https://ideone.com/y5bPwS ... obviously `reinterpret_cast<int*>(buffer, 0)` returns wrong pointer ... https://ideone.com/F5gMXr

Comment: Thanks Selvin, this seems to help me a lot...to navigate in my buffer I have to use the adress of the field in the char array instead of just the field. means that <pre>reinterpret_cast<int*>(&buffer[1]); <code>seem to work for me. I will check all my datatypes now

Comment: Edit solved by setting higher precision to cout...dumb fault by me.    int precision = std::numeric_limits<double>::max_digits10;
 std::cout << std::setprecision(precision) << double_p << std::endl;